# Delphi 2010 object inspector grid and windows dpi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-ide

I work on high resolution wide screen and I set the dpi to 144 so I can see fonts better.

the problem in Delphi 2010 object inspect grid I cant see the text of properties or event names the grid does not scale !!

any solution to this ?

thank

Answer (score 0):

After read your post I asked Uwe Schuster if would be possible to fix this issue with their great "Object Inspector Expert" and he did.

You can download it here:
http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2012/07/15/oi-rev-5/

Comment: The website is offline but I found this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1992068/Share/Static/UweSchuster/index.html