# Is there a fix for object inspector grid height ? Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I had to change the windows font scale to 150% so I can see more clearly but the object inspector grid now cropping properties name, is there a fix for that ?

This is Delphi 2010

[image]

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of Delphi, or switch to a smaller font scaling

Comment: I have to use this version will try to reduce scale

Comment: Delphi 10.1 berlin version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this works as i haven't tried it myself.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1992068/Share/Static/UweSchuster/index.html

From: [Delphi 2010 object inspector grid and windows dpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443868/delphi-2010-object-inspector-grid-and-windows-dpi?rq=1)